# Python - Decrypt Tripple Des AES - ECB

Tags: python, tripledes

I need to perform a decryption using TripleDes, I'm using Python - Crypto.Cipher import AES

Goodnight,

I'm trying to decrypt a 3Des key, but without success.

I'm doing it like this:

```
m = md5(key.encode('ISO-8859-1')).digest()
cipher = AES.new(m, AES.MODE_ECB)
```

Then I try to do the decryption:

```
x = bytes(password, 'ISO-8859-1')
b = cipher.decrypt(x)
```

It should return something like

```
0412719876FEDCBA
```

But it returns:

```
b'\x1e\xec\xd6A\xb13\xcf\x14N9\xa3\xb6\xdfZ\xf5\xbe'
```

In hexadecimal:

```
ac6b1433d25c07bd3853b293cbf719db
```

I know it's kind of vague, but does anyone have any light??

Comment: Are you decrypting triple DES, or AES? Triple DES and AES are different.

Comment: In the documentation is:

Script to decrypt PINBlock ISO Format 0 3DES

Comment: If you are trying to decrypt 3DES why are you using AES? That is like trying to use a German translator to translate a document written in Spanish.

Comment: actually I'm reading some tutorials because it's my first contact with Tripple Des
Maybe this is more correct:

        key = '6B43C8417C9270F00DCED51EDDE68E11'
        pass1 = 'C9C4D04C21FC618F'


            key_hash = md5(key).digest()
            tdes_key = DES3.adjust_key_parity(key_hash)
            a = DES3.new(tdes_key, DES3.MODE_ECB)

need to decrypt pass1.

Comment: At this point you are changing the question in the comments. This makes the question a moving target. Please ask one question and stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

Soluction

```
        key = '6B43C8417C9270F00DCED51EDDE68E11'
        binaryText = binascii.unhexlify(key)

        text = 'C9C4D04C21FC618F'
        text = binascii.unhexlify(str.encode(text, 'Utf-8'))

        k = pyDes.triple_des(binaryText, pyDes.ECB)
        ret = k.decrypt(text)
        print("Descrypt Value = %r" % binascii.hexlify(ret))
        print('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@')
```

xor

```
        a = binascii.hexlify(encrypted)
        pk = a.decode('iso-8859-1')
        x = pk.upper()
        print(x)
        x1 = x
        x2 = '0000456789012345' #card pan format
        a = [( ord (a) ^ ord (b)) for a , b in zip(x1 , x2)]
        print(a)
```